# show custom messages in jquery validate engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validation-engine

There are two fields username and password and I used `validate[required]` class.

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="Enter your username" type="text">
<input id="password" name="password" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="Enter your password" type="password">
```

```js
jQuery("#loginForm").validationEngine('attach', {
    promptPosition: "topRight", 
    scroll: false
});
```

Now when I click on the submit button it shows its standard messages, but I want to show my custom messages. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean custom and standard messages

Comment: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#custom_error_messages

Comment: standard messages like if I applied validate[required] then it shows field is required. And messages I mean own messgaes

Comment: @Jai, can you please give an example on fiddle, because I tried this and its not working

Comment: could you plz provide the fiddle for it to play.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it wasn't working for you.  Here is a working example.

Javascript

```
$("#formID2").validationEngine({'custom_error_messages' : {
        '#text1' : {
            'required': {
                'message': "Why you no give name?"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="formID2">
    <label for="text1">Please enter your name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="validate[required]" id="text1" />
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pt4tjdtd/

Comment: I have used var jquery_Lower_1_7_2 = $.noConflict(true); in my index.html
and now I am using

jquery_Lower_1_7_2("#loginForm").validationEngine({'custom_error_messages': {
            '#username': {
                'required': {
                    'message': "Why you no give name?"
                }
            }
        }
    });

And still this is showing 'This field is required'